# Has Data ever made a joke intentionally (not involuntarily) in the TNG series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

I know Data tried to make Laforge laugh with his Mr. Tricorder parody in Star Trek: Generations Movie when he had this "emotion chip"

[image]

Aside from this I only know the episode in TNG where Q loses his powers, being a simple human, and when returns to being omnipotent giving the Data the gift to laugh the very first time (as I recall).

Was there an episode, where Data makes jokes intentionally and the crew is not laughing at him? Lore made some jokes, but he was bit cynical.

Comment: In the second part of the episode _[Descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29)_ Data makes some jokes. However, due to the lopsided emotions that Lore was feeding to Data they were of a dark nature and were not found funny by the crew.

Comment: Jokes he can't do (or so the script says), but he's being sarcastic all the time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In [The Outrageous Okona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outrageous_Okona) Data attempts to learn comedy with the help of the Holodeck.

He tells multiple jokes to a holographic audience, but realizes that he does not "get" humor, and the laughter is simply because that is what the holodeck deems the appropriate response.  He does make a joke at the end that the crew finds funny. However, Data is merely mimicking the joke, and doesn't actually understand why it is funny.

Comment: "Take my Worf.. Please..."

Comment: "My timing is digital" - Data, to Guinan

Comment: Joe Piscopo cameo in Outrageous Okono!!

Comment: I loved the comedy scene. So real. You go to a comedy show and laugh because you're at a comedy show, not because the comedian is actually any good. You don't even realise it.

Answer (score 9):

Also, in the episode "Code of Honor", Data tries to tell Geordi a joke and fails, then inadvertently makes him laugh.

[Link to clip](http://youtu.be/YlfNoZmdXrs)

Comment: Yes!  Includiling the kittilies!  Classic data line.

Comment: "This video is private". :(

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't post link-only answers.

Answer (score 8):

In [TNG: In Theory](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_Theory_(episode)) Data uses the situation to make a witty remark. O'Brien and Keiko were talking about how she picks up his socks, and he says

> "*And a very good job she does of it, too.*"

Data's date, Jenna D'Sora is says that Data ended up cleaning her room and he replies, with a wink,

> "*And a very good job of it I did of it, too.*"

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. Could you add the season and episode number of the episode you mentioned? That would make your answer better. Thanks.

Comment: @amflare - Show, don't tell

Comment: This is a really good answer. I've taken the liberty of editing in a link to the [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Portal:Main) site, using [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/199.htm) to double-check the quotes and I've created a gif of the scene using a piece of software called [LiceCAP](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Comment: "You seem to have an aversion to orderliness" -Data

Answer (score 5):

I recall an episode where Riker and Troi were getting back together, (Possibly the episode "Second Chances"?) and she disliked his beard, and so Riker shaved it off. Data noticed the change in the turbolift, and Riker commented "Smooth as an android's behind".  After getting off, Data stops Riker, and asks "May I?" motioning to feel his face.  Data then made a disapproving expression and shook his head.

Whether one can call the above episode a "joke" is certainly up to interpretation, but it shows a certain humor awareness on Data's part that is not involuntary.

I remember this moment quite vividly, though I cannot place it in its full context. The subtleness of the moment seemed a little atypically human for Data.

Comment: <nitpick>Actually, that was in Star Trek 9 - Insurrection.</nitpick>

Comment: Nitpick appreciated... I had utterly forgotten where that scene was from, just that it was the TNG crew.

Comment: It was atypical because he had his emotion chip by now. The "disapproving expression" was more of a jovial tut-tut "haha dude what are you like" sly grin. Pretty impressive move for an android with simulated feelings, when as a human I can neither properly describe the action nor explain why any of us would do it... yet I know intuitively that we would!

Answer (score 3):

Also in *Star Trek: Generations*, I think preceding the tricorder joke, Data fiddles with his arm, then waves in front of a door to make it open. He then makes a crack about having a magnetic personality.